# C#/ASP: How to handle exception from pages in master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, master-pages

I was wondering if there is any way for exception being handled in master page. Let's assume this very simple situation:

`Site.Master:`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DoStuffFromChildPage(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

`Default.aspx:`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Test Exception");
    }
```

This is just a simple overview of my idea/concept. I'm trying to prevent writing try..catch code blocks in every single page which uses master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while ago and never found any real good way.  All other options ended up being more complicated than it was worth.  You can look into not using try/catch at all and just using custom error pages instead, but i'm not sure that's what you want.

You can also make your own central exception handler, and while you're still putting a try/catch in both the page and masterpage, at least they'll be handled in the same place.